# convert PDF magazines to TV viewable dual image format

Tags: image, bash, pdf, imagemagick

How can I convert magazines in PDF format to be viewable on a TV? My TV can't display pdf, but only images, and since it is a wide screen display, showing double pages at once makes sense. Till now I used a solution, that implies the following steps:

1., use pdfnup (part of the pdfjam package) to convert the magazines to double page format (practically a pdf file where the single pages are dual page of the original file)

```
pdfnup inputfile.pdf --pages '{},1-' --outfile dualpagefile.pdf
```

due to the parameter `--pages '{},1-'` the first page - the cover of the magazine - of the inputfile.pdf is adjoined with an empty page.

2., convert the dualpage version document to images viewable on TV

```
convert -density 150 dualpagefile.pdf imagefiles_%03d.jpg
```

The problem with this solution is, that the pagesize in the dualpagefile.pdf is exactly the same as in the original inputfile.pdf, resulting in white margins at the top and bottom of the dualpagefile.pdf pages.

Now I am looking for a simpler and maybe a quicker solution, without the white stripes.

I am trying to convert the inputfile.pdf first to imagefiles, and then adjoin them to double pages images, but I don't know how to use the `convert --adjoin` command for a series of images, where the first page is left as is, or adjoined with an empty page.

Is there any elegant solution for this problem: to convert a pdf to a sequence of dual page images, with an individual cover page?

Comment: Have a look at the `montage` function. You can write a bash script to iteratively adjoin 2 images.

Comment: Thanks Nunoxic. I can't really see the difference between `convert -adjoin` and `montage` for my case. I would need a command that could process a sequence of images, always join a pair of two suceeding images side by side.

Comment: If Nunoxic helped you, you should express your "Thank you" by *upvoting* his answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not the best at bash but here is something you could try.
This requires all the files to be numbered from book-0.jpg, book-1.jpg all the way to book-n.jpg. (This can be achieved by `convert <filename>.pdf book.jpg`)

```
#!/bin/bash
one=1
num_files=$(ls *.jpg | wc -l)
for ((i=0; i<=$(($num_files-$one)); i+=2))
do
j=$(($i+$one)) 
montage -adjoin  book-$i.jpg book-$j.jpg Page_$i.jpg
done
echo "Process Finished"
```

I'm pretty sure there is a better way of doing it but this way works as well.

You can edit that `montage -adjoin ..` line and add you density, quality settings as you want.

Comment: Thanks Nunoxic!
The iterative part is working nicely, but the `montage -adjoin` results in small thumbnails. I used `convert -append` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nunoxic's idea, the final code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: pdf2tv inputfile.pdf
FILENAME=$1                         # the inputfile
FILENAME_NOEXT=${FILENAME/\/*\//};      # the inputfile without extension
FILENAME_NOEXT=${FILENAME_NOEXT/.*/};   # the inputfile without extension and additional points in the name
FILENAME_NOWSP=${FILENAME_NOEXT// /_}; # substitute spaces with underscores
TVRESOL='1920x1080'                    # TV resolution

mkdir $FILENAME_NOWSP                  # make a directory for the generated images
cd $FILENAME_NOWSP

convert -density 150 -resize ${TVRESOL} "../${FILENAME}" ${FILENAME_NOWSP}.jpg    # convert pdf's pages to jpg
num_files=$(ls ${FILENAME_NOWSP}*.jpg | wc -l)          # number of jpgs    
mv ${FILENAME_NOWSP}-0.jpg Page_001.jpg                    # the cover page
counter=2
for ((i=1; i<=$(($num_files-1)); i+=2))
do
  j=$(($i+1)) 
  outfilename=Page_`printf %03d.jpg $counter`
  # appending 2 adjacent pages into a dual page image
  convert +append ${FILENAME_NOWSP}-$i.jpg ${FILENAME_NOWSP}-$j.jpg -resize '100%x100%' $outfilename
  rm ${FILENAME_NOWSP}-{$i,$j}.jpg  # removing the temporary single images
  ((counter+=1))
done
echo "Process Finished"
```